# Plotting colored surface from 3 vectors

Tags: matlab, vector, colors, surface

I have 3 vectors:

```
time = (600:900),
depth <1 x 301>
Indice < 1 x 301 >
```

I want to plot the time in the axis, y in the abscissa.

Whereas Indice, will present the color of the surface between `The plot` and the `axis`.

Please how can I do that with Matlab?

Comment: "_I want to plot the time in the axis, y in the abscissa._" This doesn't mean anything. Can you be more specific ? How is your surface defined ?